# What is the purpose of converting uint64_t to void type in C++?

Tags: c++

I see the following code in [RocksDB's source code](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/v5.14.2/table/full_filter_block.cc#L112):

```
bool FullFilterBlockReader::KeyMayMatch(const Slice& key, uint64_t block_offset,
                                        const bool /*no_io*/,
                                        const Slice* const /*const_ikey_ptr*/) {
#ifdef NDEBUG
  (void)block_offset;
#endif
  assert(block_offset == kNotValid);
  if (!whole_key_filtering_) {
    return true;
  }
  return MayMatch(key);
}
```

`(void)block_offset` is a type conversion and its result is unused. So `(void)block_offset` is used for its side effect. What is its side effect here?

Comment: The compiler won't warn for an unused parameter.

Comment: There is no side effect, in terms of working of the code.   However, if `NDEBUG` is defined, `assert()` is a macro that does nothing, so a fair few compilers (with appropriate compilation options) detect `block_offset` as being an unused variable and issue a warning.    `(void)block_offset` causes most of those compilers to suppress the warning.

Comment: I think I would drop the #ifdef as it relies on assuming the behaviour of assert(). The cast to void can be there for both versions.

Comment: @WilliamJBagshaw: The behavior of `assert` in terms of `NDEBUG` is well specified.

Comment: `-Wunused-parameter -DNDEBUG` for gcc will give a warning `warning: unused parameter ‘block_offset’ [-Wunused-parameter]`. @MrTux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is being done purely to suppress a potential compiler warning about unused parameters.

If in release builds `assert` is defined as:

```
#define assert( expr )
```

as `block_offset` is only used inside the assertion the compiler might warn that the parameter is unused as this is usually indicative of a bug. The other way of suppressing the warning is by using unnamed arguments (as with `no_io` and `const_ikey_ptr`). You could suppress the warning like this too:

```
bool FullFilterBlockReader::KeyMayMatch(const Slice& key,
                                        uint64_t 
                                        #ifdef NDEBUG
                                          block_offset
                                        #endif
                                        ,
                                        const bool /*no_io*/,
                                        const Slice* const /*const_ikey_ptr*/) {
  assert(block_offset == kNotValid);
  if (!whole_key_filtering_) {
    return true;
  }
  return MayMatch(key);
}
```

But it isn't so readable. Its more usual to be explicit about what you are doing by having an unused parameter macro which does the same thing:

```
#define UNUSED_PARAM( param ) (void)param

void f( int a )
{
    UNUSED_PARAM( a );
}
```

Qt defines `Q_UNUSED`: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#Q_UNUSED.

Boost has `ignore_unused`: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/core/doc/html/core/ignore_unused.html